# Azure functions blob trigger guarantee FIFO

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, fifo

we have a `blob trigger azure function` which processes blobs from a `adls blob storage`. We want a way to make sure that messages are processed in an order, exactly in `FIFO` order. I know that `Service Bus Queue` ensures this functionality but we can't use the Service Bus. Is there any way to achieve this with a the `blob trigger azure function` and `adls blob storage`?

Answer (score 0):

No, Azure Storage Queue doesn't guarantee FIFO.